# How to build a jar from a multi-module project when using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build, jar, dependencies

I'm working on a multi-module *library* project which I build with Gradle. I have a dependency to another module of this project in my `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':my-other-module')
}
```

My problem is that I want to build a `.jar` file which only contains the local modules in the final file, not its transitive dependencies. I tried this:

```
jar {
    from project(':my-other-module').configurations.compile.collect { zipTree it }
}
```

but this added all the transitive dependencies as well. I want to create a `.jar` which only contains my own files, so the users of this library can have their own versions of transitive dependencies. How can I do so?

**Further clarification:**

I have dependencies declared in my project to external jars like `apache-commons`. I want these *not to be* in my resulting `.jar` file but I want the users of my library to be able to just add my library as a dependency and let `Maven`/`Gradle` download the transitive dependencies. I don't want these transitive dependencies to *be* in the `.jar` file I deploy to Maven Central. `compileOnly` is not an option since the dependencies I use like `apache-commons` are not provided by a framework or a container. They need to be present as `compile` dependencies. I just want to build and deploy a `.jar` file which has **all** the files in **my project** which has multiple modules.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it'll help you or not but, you can try this.

In your build.gradle file, customize your jar task as follows:

```
// This closure will return the full directory path of folder where your classes are built
ext.moduleClassPath = { moduleName ->
    def classOutputDirConst = "/classes/java/main"
    return "${project(":${moduleName}").buildDir}${classOutputDirConst}"
}

// Now jar task will include only the built file of specified project
jar {
    from(moduleClassPath("projectName1"), moduleClassPath("projectName2"))
}
```

**Check the reference for the from(SourcePaths) method here:** Reference: [https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar.html#org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar:from(java.lang.Object[])](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar.html#org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar:from(java.lang.Object%5B%5D))

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has a [compile-only dependency concept](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies), similar to Maven's provided scope:

> Compile-only dependencies are distinctly different than regular compile dependencies. They are not included on the runtime classpath and they are non-transitive, meaning they are not included in dependent projects.

The dependencies you don't want can be declared in the compileOnly configuration, rather than compile, eg:

`dependencies {
    compileOnly 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}`

`compileOnly` is not even visible to unit tests, by default. We change this in a common gradle snippet which we include in each build:

```
// compileOnly isn't visible to tests by default, add it
plugins.withType(JavaPlugin).whenPluginAdded {
    sourceSets {
        test.compileClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
        test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.compileOnly
    }
}
```

For the second part, for which I believe you want to create a single "fat" jar, 
I would suggest creating your jar using the very good [Shadow Plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/), rather than manually extending the jar task. By default, the shadow plugin will not include anything in the `compileOnly` configuration in the resulting jar.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question I was asking. My problem is that if I build a project which has dependencies to a local project they are not in the final `jar` file. I want them to be in that jar.

Comment: That's what the shadow plugin does, except by default, it will include transitive as well as local projects, which you've stated you don't want, hence the suggestion of compileOnly. Have you tried the above?

Comment: I'll take a look then.

Comment: So my problem is that the dependencies I have in my project are not `provided`. I'm working on a library and I want to build a `.jar` file which can be deployed and it *only contains* the local files (the 3 modules of my multi-module project) and the rest of the dependencies are transitive. They will be handled by whomever uses this library. So I think that `compileOnly` here won't work because those are not `compileOnly` dependencies, they are needed in the downstream project written by the user. To sum it up: I want to build a `.jar` with all the files in **my** project but **nothing else**.

Comment: So use `compileOnly` on the dependencies you *don't* want included, and `compile` (or `runtime`) on the dependencies you *do* want included. Otherwise http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#configuring_shadowed_dependencies describes more custom ways to control the contents of the resulting jar, eg using regex.

Comment: But do my users have to re-add the `compileOnly` dependencies in their project? I want to deliver a full package as a single-line dependency in their config file.

Comment: Ok, so you want to not include the transitive dependencies, but you still want them declared as runtime dependencies for downstream users? So sounds like you aren't just building a jar, but a pom.xml also. You could try using explicit config of the shadowJar plugin to control that, and seeing if it generates the right pom (I haven't tried it). But why not just publish each project individually to maven? Users would pull in related projects automatically along with other transitive dependencies.